# ConcurrentModificationException when using iter.hasNext()

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

I have a `producer` `consumer` setup using a `Wildfly` AS for `JMS`, the producer uses a `newFixedThreadPool(126)` every 1 minute each thread is pulling data down from a `REST` service and is pushing it onto a `HornetQ`on the `Wildfly` AS.

Then on the consumer side I have a Consumer class that consumes the messages in the `HornetQ` and a simple `Parser` class, for DB insertion, I'm trying to buffer the DB insertions and I'm getting an Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException I suspect this has something to do with my code not being thread safe, but I can't narrow it down.

Consumer:

```
    public void Consume(Consumer asyncReceiver) throws Throwable {

        try (javax.jms.Connection connection = connFactory.createConnection(props.getProperty("DEFAULT_USERNAME"), props.getProperty("
             Session queueSession = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

             MessageConsumer msgConsumer = queueSession.createConsumer(queue)) {

            msgConsumer.setMessageListener(asyncReceiver);

            connection.setExceptionListener(asyncReceiver);

            connection.start();

            /** I think this is causing the problem */
            System.out.println("waiting for messages");
            int bufferCount = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 47483647; i++) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.print(".");
                if (bufferCount == 5) {
                    if(responseList.size() > 50){
                        this.buffer();
                    }
                    bufferCount = 0;
                }
                bufferCount++;
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.severe(e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    } finally {
        if (context != null) {
            context.close();
        }
    }
    if (connection != null) {
        connection.close();
    }
}

public void buffer() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Parsing: " + responseList.size() + " messages");
        Parser parser = new Parser();
        parser.addList(responseList);
        parser.parseApplication();
        responseList.clear();
}

@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    TextMessage msg = (TextMessage) message;
    try {
        responseList.add(msg.getText());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Parser:

```
public class Parser {

private ArrayList<String> responseList;


public void addList(ArrayList<String> list) {
    this.responseList = list;
}

public void parseApplication() throws Exception {

    DBConnection db = DBConnection.createApplication();

    try (Connection connection = db.getConnection()) {

//Code removed for stack question

        Iterator<String> iter = responseList.iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()) {

// This is where the error is thrown 
            while (fieldsIterator.hasNext()) {

            //Cut code from here, basic JSON parsing done here
               timeslices = parse(iter.Next())

                for (int i = 0; i < timeslices.length(); i++) {

                        ThroughputEntry TP = new ThroughputEntry();
                        TP.setThroughput(values.getDouble(name));
                        TP.setEnvironment(envName);
                        TP.setName(appName);
                        TP.setRetrieved(from);
                        TP.setPeriodEnd(to);
                        db.addHistory(TP);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        iter.remove();
    }
}
}
```

Maybe I should make my buffer method into a `threadpool` ?

Comment: Wow... a lot of code here with no clear information in the question as to where exactly in the code your error is happening. Can you clear this up and reduce the amount of code?

Comment: This is a code-dump. Please make a [mcve].

Comment: I've cleaned up the code, I'm not sure where the issue is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
responseList.add(msg.getText());
```

modifies the list while your parser is iterating on it.
In this case the iterator throws a `ConcurrentModificationException`.
To fix it you should copy the list before parsing.

Comment: I tried copying the list already in the `Parser` class and I got the same error, the error is thrown in the `Parser` class

Comment: Well after the edit there is no more code left to cause the error.

Comment: I think the error is being caused in the code that is left, I have missed something somewhere.

Comment: You were right, I forgot I needed to do a shallow copy with an `ArrayList`, rookie mistake, thanks